# not able to send more than one mail in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to send a mail to more than one person at a time.

My code is like this;

```
 Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("jasibs002@gmail.com", "someMadeUpPassword")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            Dim omail As New MailMessage()

        omail.From = New MailAddress("jasibs002@gmail.com", "JaseemBinBacker", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        omail.Subject = "Test Mail"
        Dim str As String
        str = "Hai How Are You I am Sendig This Mail for Testing"
        str = str + vbNewLine & "Checking"
        str = str + vbNewLine & "Sucess"
        omail.Body = str
        Dim email As String
        Dim cmdemail As New SqlCommand("SELECT Emailid FROM  dbo.Email_tbl", con.connect)
        dr = cmdemail.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            email = dr("Emailid")
            omail.To.Add(email)

        End While
        dr.Close()
        con.disconnect()
     SmtpServer.SendAsync(omail, Nothing)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

While executing this, I am getting the following error;
`An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.`

My Email `Table` has more than 10 email ids.

Comment: yes sir...i want to send to all

Comment: You are sending a separate email per iteration of your loop, instead of just sending one email to everyone.

Comment: @Heslacher.  Good catch.  Not sure if it was the real one or not, but I changed it to something more obtuse in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your While loop to:

```
    While dr.Read
        email = dr("Emailid")
        omail.To.Add(email)

    End While
    SmtpServer.SendAsync(omail, Nothing)
```

Comment: sir in my Email Table I have 10 more email id.if i given like this i can send email to that email id's??

Comment: no sir..if i given SmtpServer.SendAsync(omail, Nothing) after end while it will send last item of dr("Emailid") in your datareader

Comment: i check mails ,mail is coming only the last mail address

Comment: no..only the message body..sir i want to send mail to all mail id coming from  dr("Emailid")

Comment: if i give SmtpServer.endAsync(omail, Nothing) after the end while it will only execute after executing while loop..so how to take all email form table?

Comment: i edited my question as per your suggestion..please look into that

Comment: message box all mail id from the tabel

Comment: am very sory sir,,actully mail is going to spam folde..that why i not able to recoganize mail is getting or not? any how thanks for your help